# Why has self-regulation of social media failed?

Tags: privacy

Canadian Minister of Democratic Institutions, Katrina Gould, has said that ‘all options are on the table’ when it comes to regulating social media companies as she recognised that ‘self-regulation has failed’ and that Canada is talking to other partners ‘worldwide’. Mark Zuckerberg has also recently published an open letter where he says that self-regulation isn’t working either and that he wants governments to take a more robust role.

However, the articles I’ve looked at have been somewhat vague in how self-regulation has failed.

Q. What are the main areas of failure, for say a social media company like Facebook?

Comment: This question could be improved by clarifying what aspect of social media operation is being discussed. The one answer posted so far seems to assume it's about privacy. But as far as I know the discussion is actually about censoring hate speech. There are also a lot of other aspects of social media website one *could* regulate but which might not be what this question is actually about.

Comment: @phillip: content moderation is what was on my mind when I was asking this. But I was looking for the broader picture, that is the main areas where failures are occurring.

Comment: In that case the question would be too broad and opinion-based (because different people from our community will have different ideas about what aspects should and should not be regulated). Can you edit your question and make clear that what Katrina Gould is talking about is content moderation?

Comment: @Philipp: The article I looked at did not say she was specifically talking about the failure of content moderation. This is why I’m asking for more specifics, but like I said, broadly constituted. I don’t think asking for the main areas of concern is particularly opinion-based, it’s a matter of justifying each area of concern. For example, with privacy, the Cambridge Analytica scandal shows that there is wide concern. Social media addiction is another I’ve come across as is the pervasive availability of porn.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in that case the question is too broad. Your question must tell the reader what you are actually asking about. You can't let the answer authors decide for themselves how they want to interpret the question and then talk about their favorite pet-issue of social media. We are looking for answers which are comprehensively answering the question in all aspects. And if you don't clearly define those aspects, that's impossible. Please pick one specific aspect of social media which is considered for regulation and edit it into the question. The question can then be reopened.

Comment: @Philipp: I’m leaving as is. As I’ve already said, I don’t consider asking ‘what the main areas of failure’ to be a vague and broad question that is capable of a hundred different variations. We’ll just have to differ on this.

Comment: The problem is that the claim that self-regulation has failed seems to come mostly from people who have a vested interest in increased regulation, either because they're politicians & bureaucrats who see a chance for empire-building, or because they want to suppress those whose tastes & opinions are at odds with their own religious/social views.

Comment: @jamesqf: You seem to be very sure of yourself here, however, Mark Zuckerberg of Facebook is on record saying that they need help as well as Jack Dorsey of Twitter. I don’t think they’re looking for help from the average joe, and so we can read that as a mea culpa that they need the government to step in. The main question is how that’s going to happen.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: Calll me a cynic (I think I'm a realist :-)), but I think you misinterpret Zuckerberg et. al..  They know that there is a political movement in favor of regulation.  I suspect they hope to co-opt some of that, so that if regulation is enforced, it will not interfere with the money-earning abilities of their businesses.

Answer (score 2):

*It is against the business model.*

Social media companies make money by selling the users' data. Any regulation would curb the extent to which user data can be employed.

If the chemical, or many other, industry had self-regulation in place for environmental protection, we be much worse off regarding the environment.

Environmental/consumer protection does not make money, so corporations don't make it a priority; however, if regulator make missing environmental/consumer protection a finable offense, then corporation will at least meet the standards to avoid cost.

Comment: A rational for Mr. Z to argue the case for governmental regulation is, that with government regulation in place, social media companies have a guideline for avoiding fines. Now, it's the wild west, and sometimes they are fined for being too egregious. Being more modest in the user-data usage, as to not come across as total creeps, is not an option since there is so much sweet money to make. Government regulation essentially shifts the blame. The latest data-scandal: happened on the governments watch, as it was not illegal.